# Alternative to browser tabs?

Tags: browser

My tabs always get completely out of hand while developing, such that I can't read anything or navigate anywhere. If anyone has solved this, what tool are you using to better manage your browser windows? Open to any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Would be better asked on http://superuser.com/questions

Comment: this is programming related?

Comment: @TZHX: No, but there is no option to migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** This feature has since gone the way of the Reading List. There are third-party add-ons that recreate the behavior.

**Firefox 4 features the [Panorama](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-panorama) tab management system** which allows you to drag-and-drop tabs into groups and switch between groups. It gives you greater flexibility over the tabs that you see without forcing you to manage multiple windows or close out tabs.

Comment: This looks amazing. Here's to hoping they come out with something similar for Chrome soon...

Comment: FWIW, I've been using FF4 for some months now and I never once used this feature. Perhaps I'm getting old (I ought to be below 20, but ...), but I couldn't integrate it into my workflow (as in, I still open everything in tabs in the same single group). Quite the contrary - it got in my way a few times, Ctrl-E is too close to Ctrl-W (quite a surprise when you hit it the first time) and I was left wondering where the heck my tabs went a few times (bugs, but still).

Comment: @delnan honestly I don't use it either because I rarely have more than 5-6 tabs open at once, but I know power users who don't know how they lived without it

Comment: @delnan I've found binding the Panorama shortcut key to a button on the mouse makes it a lot easier to access and so much more useful.

Comment: Update: "The Tab Groups (Panorama) feature has been removed from Firefox. We know this may be inconvenient and we apologize. Removing the Tab Groups feature makes it easier for us to improve Firefox." https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-removal

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a plugin for your browser that provides vertical tree style tabs. The one I use is Tab Kit for firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tab-kit/

Answer (score 0):

See [Mozilla Home Dash](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prospector-home-dash/), it might be useful. It is a project of [Mozilla Labs](http://mozillalabs.com/).